# Sending a SIGSTOP to child process

Tags: process, operating-system, signals, fork, kill

I am learning about sending signals. I came across SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to pause and then continue a running process respectively. 
As far as I understand, when we execute a fork(), we do not know whether the parent or the child would execute first. It is dependent on the architecture of the process scheduler. This is why if for example after the fork we print something separately in the parent and child, the order of execution cannot be determined. (Unless we are using wait() in parent to synchronize the two processes).

 Now, I am sending a SIGSTOP signal from parent to child and then after the parent has done some computation, sending a SIGCONT signal to child to resume operation. So far, every time I run the code, no code under the child process executes. But I am wondering if this will always be the case? Could there be a situation where an instruction in the child process gets executed before it receives the SIGSTOP from its parent? Here is some sample code:

```
pid_t pid_c = fork();
if (pid_c == 0){
   printf("Hello I am the child process!\n");
}
else {
   kill(pid_c, SIGSTOP);
   printf("Hello I am the parent process!\n");
   // do some computation
   kill(pid_c, SIGCONT);
   wait(&NULL)
}
```

When I try executing the above code, the parent process always starts with printing the statements so the SIGSTOP is able to pause the child execution before it can execute anything. Does this always happen with SIGSTOP or is this just architecture dependent? I mean could there be a case where the child prints "Hello I am the child process!" before getting paused?
Any suggestions are much appreciated! Thank you!